# Links wont work inside element that have an event handler with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have a setup like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">hi</a>
</div>
```

And for some reason I have to have an event handler on the div that has preventDefault() called on it.
In Chrome (and probably other browsers) this breaks the links inside that div. I can no longer left click on them and the only way to follow the link is to right click and open in new tab.

The only solution I can think of is in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QB698/

But this solution seems so gross. Isn't there any better way to solve this so I don't have to add an event to EVERY single link that might be in a div with a preventDefault handler on it?

Thanks.

Comment: The solution is to not call `.preventDefault()` if you don't actually want to do that. "for some reason" ... what reason?

Comment: Yes, what reason do you need to preventDefault()?  The entire purpose of it is to keep the link from going to a new page?  If you want the link to go to a new page, don't preventDefault()

Comment: Not really sure why... I'm currently debugging someone else's code and the situation is kinda complicated... they claim that it's needed because when you click on a button to open a popover (the div in our case) the event bubbled to the popover and then closes it again. So maybe they should be checking targets in the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can `stopPropagation` of the click event in *capturing* phase of the event. Then you don't have to bind click event to each child link:

```
document.getElementById("asd").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QB698/1/

Comment: This works fine... But like other commens said, we should really consider if we need a prevent default. I think in my case it was also preventing a hash from appearing in the url after I clicked on the link that opened the popover. So maybe I need to not use a link... there's lots of different routes to consider.